# Tkinter unable to clear OptionMenu choice with .destroy

Tags: python, tkinter, label, optionmenu, customtkinter

I am trying to display a Label with a selected option from a customtkinter OptionMenu. I am unable to display what is currently selected into a label. I have tried two different ways and get 2 different errors.

First error that producesTypeError: on_size_selected() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given:

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import *

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")
root = customtkinter.CTk()
size_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel()

size_options = ["Random", "Tiny", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Huge", "Gargantuan"]
def on_size_selected():
    size_label.destroy() #Issue is here 
    size_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root,text=clicked.get())
    size_label.pack()


clicked= customtkinter.StringVar()
size_menu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(root, variable=clicked, values=size_options, command=on_size_selected)
size_menu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Second Error is str object has no attribute destroy (I have tried with clear as well and says same thing but with clear):

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import *

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")
root = customtkinter.CTk()

size_options = ["Random", "Tiny", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Huge", "Gargantuan"]
def on_size_selected(size_label):
    size_label.destroy() #Issue is here 
    size_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root,text=clicked.get())
    size_label.pack()


clicked= customtkinter.StringVar()
size_menu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(root, variable=clicked, values=size_options, command=on_size_selected)
size_menu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Read the CustomTkinter docs](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkOptionMenu). The OptionMenu will send a string of your choice to the command and a string has no method destroy. This should work:

```
def on_size_selected(choice):
    new_values = [x for x in size_options if x != choice]
    size_menu.configure(values=new_values)
    size_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root,text=choice)
    size_label.pack()
```

Note that you dont need a stringvar.

**Edit**
Note that CustomTkinter emulates tkinter widgets and in this case it's a normal behaviour of a tkinter widget as @martineau stated in the comments. So you may consider to read the tkinter documentation as well.

Comment: Actually this is what regular `OptionMenu` widget do, too.

Comment: @martineau thanks for pointing this out. I did notice the symmetry of course but missed the fact that `tk.Optionmenu` also provides the option for a `command` that parses the selected value.